# pie.htc file incorrectly appearing as http_referer with IE8 and IIS6

Tags: internet-explorer-8, iis-6

I'm working on a corporate intranet and we have recently redesigned it using all sorts of CSS3 goodness as specified by a design agency. Our corporate standard browser is (still) IE8 so in order to make the CSS3 work I employed CSS3 PIE (http://css3pie.com/) which recreates the CSS functionality using VML via a .htc file - and it works great. However I've noticed that the http_referer value for pages viewed in IE8 is being returned as the location for pie.htc instead of the actual referring page and it was working just fine before the redesign. Firefox is tolerated as an alternative browser and for pages viewed in that browser all the http_referer values are as they should be. This is causing quite a headache for forms which redirect using this variable, as well as the logs which dump various environment variables to database for easy querying - and the guys who analyse the stats aren't remotely happy!

I have flagged this with the developer of CSS3 PIE and it's a mystery to him, but before I register a bug I wanted to see if it might be some failing of IIS or some setting I've missed in it (I'm using version 6 on Windows 2003). We have an Linux server with Apache as well for different purposes which I redesigned using the same technique and that doesn't seem to be displaying the same behaviour.

Does anyone have any related experience with PIE or any other .htc files on IIS which they were able to solve? Or is it some kind of IE8 bug that will never be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

we experience the same issue. We removed it from the html. It could be an IE bug, I don't see any reason why the referer of the .htc should be the same as the page.

Comment: Sorry for the long time in responding. Well at least it's not just me! Unfortunately I'm not in a position to just get rid of it as replacing its functionality with images would be a massive job - and an ongoing one.